# Why isnt my jquery working when i echo it out with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to echo out to easily change videos and load it up so i can work with it and this is the code for the jquery to echo out

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <?php
    $latest = 1;
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '

          $("' . $row['vid_class'] . '").click(function() { 
          $(".video-display iframe").attr("src", "' . $row['vid_link'] . '");
          $(".video-display").toggle();
       });';
      }
    }
  ?>
</script>
```

this is what it will echo out and it doesn't run

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("into-the-unknown").click(function() {
  $(".video-display iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/DkGKLhDUN4g?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=1");
  $(".video-display").toggle();
});

$("wwoman").click(function() {
  $(".video-display iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/VSB4wGIdDwo?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=1");
  $(".video-display").toggle();
});
</script>
```

And it is called after the jquery tag to make it work just above the body

Comment: does it fail with an error message? your Jquery seems to not be wrapped in an onload event handler, so it seems like it could execute before the DOM is complete

Comment: @slackOverflow it does not work with the $(document).ready(function() {}); or without and it hasnt spit out an error at all

Comment: Shouldn't this `$("into-the-unknown")` be rather `$(".into-the-unknown")` (added the dot to denote class reference)?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil thank you so much *facepalms* i thank you so much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot to include `.` in the generated jQuery code to denote class reference.

Change:

```
echo '
      $("' . $row['vid_class'] . '").click(function() { 
      $(".video-display iframe").attr("src", "' . $row['vid_link'] . '");
      $(".video-display").toggle();
   });';
```

to

```
echo '
      $(".' . $row['vid_class'] . '").click(function() { 
      $(".video-display iframe").attr("src", "' . $row['vid_link'] . '");
      $(".video-display").toggle();
   });';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the jQuery selectors: `.` or `#`

I'm not really sure how you are trying to grab the elements: by id or by class.
One thing for sure is that you are trying either one of these and you are grabbing by tag-name only.

Try changing the

```
$("' . $row['vid_class'] . '").click(function()
```

to

```
$(."' . $row['vid_class'] . '").click(function() //If you are using class
```

or

```
$(#"' . $row['vid_class'] . '").click(function() //If you are using id
```

wherever it is applicable.

Hope this helps!